# Calculate the difference between two timestamp objects java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, timestamp, criteria

The problem is: I used criteria to take from my database the maximum value of "startDate" and "endDate". Now I have to find the difference between these two objects which are in the database timestamp.

Does anyone know how to do?

**taskTimes.java**

```
public Object taskTimes() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Task.class).setProjection(Projections.max("endDate"));
        Object avgDate = (Object) criteria.uniqueResult();

        Criteria criteria1 = session.createCriteria(Task.class).setProjection(Projections.max("startDate"));
        Object avgDate1 = (Object) criteria1.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println(avgDate);
        System.out.println(avgDate1);
        session.close();

        return avgDate;
    }
```

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int batch;

    @Column
    private java.sql.Timestamp startDate;

    @Column
    private java.sql.Timestamp endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    private Job job;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
    private List<Result> results;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Job getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public Task(Long id, int batch, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate, Student student, Job job,
            List<Result> results) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.batch = batch;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.student = student;
        this.job = job;
        this.results = results;
    }

    public java.sql.Timestamp getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(java.sql.Timestamp startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public java.sql.Timestamp getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(java.sql.Timestamp endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public Task() {

    }

    public int getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(int batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task [id=" + id;
    }
```

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` inherits from `java.util.Date`.  Calculating the difference between two `Date` objects is simple.  I suggest you go back and read the Javadoc.

Comment: i can't cast from timestamp to Date

Comment: You might not be able to cast from Timestamp to java.util.Date, but you should be able to cast from Timestamp to java.sql.Date.

Comment: Aside of previous correct answers, can it be simpler to add calculated column into SQL to get right out of Database and do not care about Java?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API of [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) it offers a method getTime().

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Timestamp object.

To calculate the difference you could use a combination of this method and `Math.abs`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Objects are of type Timestamp, typecast them to Timestamp

```
Timestamp avgDateTs = (Timestamp)avgDate;
Timestamp avgDateTs1 = (Timestamp)avgDate1;
```

Then get the time in milliseconds.

```
long timeInMills = avgDateTs.getTime();
long timeInMills1 = avgDateTs1.getTime();
```

Do a diff of the millisecond values, that would give you the difference in milliseconds.

You can then divide by 1000 to get the difference in seconds.

```
long differenceInSecs = (timeInMills1-timeInMills)/1000;
```